# Escape special characters both „ and “ in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex, sql-server-2008

I have a product name with  `„ “` characters. How can escape both ( `„` and `“`) characters in SQL Server.

I have tried the following.

```
SELECT REPLACE('ts. & dot. test testing. „G“ ', '\„\“', '');
```

Comment: Use the `replace` function twice

Comment: I would ask why I need to change this unicode data.  It would seem to me that you should update your app/database to handle characters like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to escape either, just need nested `REPLACE()` statements:

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE('ts. & dot. test testing. „G“ ', '„', ''),'“','');
```

Returns: `ts. & dot. test testing. G`

`REPLACE()` is looking for a literal string to replace, in your example the literal string `„“` never occurs, so nothing is replaced.